# For which t values the two vectors are parallel to each other

Tags: vectors, cross-product

$\overrightarrow{r_{1}}(t)=[t+6,-3,t+2]$

$\overrightarrow{r_{2}}(t)=[-10,t+7,-2t^{2}]$

For which t values the two vectors are parallel to each other?

My try:

I tried cross product, and got :
$$\left[5t^{2}-9t-14,2t^{3}+12t^{2}-10t-20,t^{2}+13t+12\right]$$

so if both vectors are parallel :

$$
\begin{cases}
5t^{2}-9t-14=0\\
2t^{3}+12t^{2}-10t-20=0\\
t^{2}+13t+12=0
\end{cases}
$$

but I don't get a solution :(

any idea?

Comment: Muliplty the third equation by $5$ and subtract from the first. You get  $t=-1$.

Comment: I'm so stupid thanks mate